# Jquery и DOM Iframe

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe

Не работает, в чем причина? Приложил фидл.

```
if ($("#page").contents().find(".searchheader").text() == "") 
    {
        $("#a").text("Не загрузилось", $("#page").contents().find(".searchheader").text());
    }
else {
    $("#a").text("Загрузилось");
    alert ($("#page").contents().find(".searchheader").text());
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/jcSXy/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в том, что документ и iframe находятся на разных доменах.